# Frobenius method on Laplace equation in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, frobenius-method

After [separating variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434340/separation-of-variables-on-a-polar-laplace-ivbp) in a Laplace equation in polar coordinates, I have to solve the resulting Bessel equation for the $R$-variables (the $\Theta$ variable I do not consider in this post as it yields a regular exponential function):
$$
\begin{equation}
R_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}R_r+(1-\frac{\lambda}{r^2})R=0
\end{equation}
$$
I used the Frobenius method, and got as follows:
I made the ansatz $R(r)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^{n+q}$, and get thus
$$
\begin{split}
R'(r) & =\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+q)a_nr^{n+q-1},\\
&\qquad\Downarrow\\
R''(r) &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+q)(n+q-1)a_nr^{n+q-2}.
\end{split}
$$
Inserting in the PDE:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+q)(n+q-1)a_nr^{n+q-2}+\frac{1}{r}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+q)a_nr^{n+q-1}+\Big(1-\frac{\lambda}{r^2}\Big)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^{n+q}=0.
$$
Simplified:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^{q+n-2}\big[(q^2+n^2)+2qn-1)\big]+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^{n+q}-\lambda\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^{n+q-2}=0
$$
Now, I set $n=0$ and get:
$$
a_0r^{q}\big[(q^2-1-\lambda)\big]+a_0r^{q}=0.
$$
Solving the quadratic equation $q^2-1-\lambda+1=0\rightarrow q=\pm\sqrt{\lambda}$.

Then, solving the recursion equation $[(n+q)^2-\lambda]a_n=a_{n-2}$
$$
a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n}}{[(n+2+q)^2-\lambda]}.
$$
But then, how does one use gamma function and beta function here? For instance, $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ and the relationship between $\Gamma$ and $\beta$ function is
$$
\begin{equation}
\beta(p,q)=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}
\end{equation}
$$
But re-writing
$$
a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n}}{[(n+2+q)^2-\lambda]},
$$
with the use of $\Gamma$ and $\beta$ is not clear to me. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Now you find the recursion equation $[(n+q)^2-λ]a_n+a_{n-2}=0$ and express the resulting expressions in terms of the Gamma, and possible Beta, function. There is a slight complication when $2\sqrtλ$ is integer.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I made a mistake there. The n should cancel out with the other -n. Corrected.

Comment: $a_{-1}$ does not exist, or for convenience, it exists with the value $0$. You need to exclude division by zero.

Comment: Thanks Lutz, but here I don't know what to do more